# FireStore when adding FCM token to User doc, deletes and doesn't store UserId

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

It's my first time using Firestore Cloud Messaging and I want to get the FCM token for each specific device. For quick development, I added the firebase_auth_ui package, which basically outsources the firebase auth login and registration flow. To capture the user's id and store in their doc, I use a simple function that works fine: and gets the job done:

```
Future<void> addUserDataToFireStore() async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  users.doc(uid).set({
    'userId': uid,
    // 'displayName': currentUser!.displayName!,
  });
}
```

Now, for some reason when I try to access the registration token, my userId gets deleted. When I try to add the token to the same user doc, the userId gets deleted and the fcm token stays. I generate the token as follows:

```
generateDeviceToken() async {
String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection('users')
      .doc(userId)
       .set({'fcmToken': fcmToken});
 }
```

The issue is when I try to call them both. I can't get the two. The doc will fill with either UserId or FCM, but now both. This is what happens when I try to call both,
[image]

Perhaps I should make a method that updates fcm token and not set it everytimg?

Answer (score 1):

When you use "set", the entire document is saved with only that one value. Use "update" to update the document and add your token without removing other content.

```
generateDeviceToken() async {
String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection('users')
      .doc(userId)
       .update({'fcmToken': fcmToken});
 }
```

```
Future<void> addUserDataToFireStore() async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  users.doc(uid).update({
    'userId': uid,
    // 'displayName': currentUser!.displayName!,
  });
}
```

Comment: I will test this out in the evening and get back to you to see if it works. Thanks for your response

Comment: You were right about update vs set. I wasn't aware of those

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my logic a little bit. Thanks to @Maniak pointing me in the rigth direction. Solution that worked out was the following:

```
Future<void> addUserDataToFireStore() async {
  final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId);
  final doc = await userDocRef.get();

  if (doc.exists) {
    return;
  } else {
    userDocRef.set({
      'userId': userId,
    });
  }
}

Future<void> generateDeviceToken() async {
  String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userId)
      .update({'fcmToken': fcmToken});
}
```